# Windows Phone 7.1 data binding confusion

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I'm trying to work out how to catch a data binding *in the act* (either intercept or post-process) to customize the display of data in the target control.

I know about `IValueConvertor` and understand that I can transform a simple value into another simple value, but I don't believe this is enough for my needs... which are:

The control in this case is a `TextBlock` and the data values from the objects in my `ObservableCollection` are variable length strings. I want to render the strings in multiple colours by splitting them into pieces and programatically creating a `<Run Foreground="xxx" Text="yyy"/>` for each piece inside the `TextBlock`.

Since the strings are variable length and the colours have to be programatically determined from the content of the string, I don't believe I can pre-create the `<Run>`s in the XAML, so I have to somehow get in on the data binding action and generate the `<Run>`s at bind-time (or very soon after).

`Binding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated` would seem to be a way to set up an event handler to do the work, but that's not available in the Windows Phone cut-down Silverlight implementation.

Any ideas? All search results seem to point to the above, but I'm looking for that little bit more.

Comment: The class you're binding to probably implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If so, you can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event, and create your controls when the event is raised

Comment: Yes, it does and I'll try that - thanks. But one thing is that event handler doesn't get an arg corresponding to the control to which the object was bound. This is an ObservableCollection bound to a ListBox so it could be any of the items. Do I just have to search to find the right one or is there some data binding trickery for finding the target for a particular source object (which the handler _will_ know)?

Comment: That didn't work. `PropertyChanged` is not firing for the initial setup of my list. I tried hooking `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged` and that _does_ fire but the controls haven't been generated yet, i.e. it's too early. According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674451/how-to-get-the-listboxitem-for-an-item-in-listbox-on-bind-time) there should be a `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event, but that seems to be absent on Windows Phone... so I'm still stuck. How can I know when the ListBoxItems are being rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having apparently exhausted all the cut-down Silverlight on Windows Phone options for programmatically hooking the rendering of ListBoxItems via the data model, I ended up adding a `Loaded="..."` event handler to the XAML for the `TextBlock`.

It doesn't feel like the nicest solution, but perhaps that's just my *code-preference* talking and it's actually the right way to do it on Windows Phone.

In any case, because I'm hooked to the `TextBlock` directly, I'm not sure how to then get to the databound object on the `ListBoxItem` containing the `TextBlock`... if anyone has advice on how to get back up the tree to the generated ListBoxItem then I could use the bound object directly instead of retrieving it from elsewhere.

Note that since the `ListBoxItem` is generated, I didn't find where to put a `Loaded="..."` event handler for that in the XAML. The `ListBox.ItemTemplate` doesn't accept a `Loaded` attribute.

**Update: this doesn't work!**

The Loaded event handler fires when the `TextBlock` is first created and loaded, so the substitution works initially.

BUT

The generated `ListBoxItem` seems to be recycled (I guess by the `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator` which doesn't want to use excessive amounts of memory by instantiating a whole new container when there are many *off-screen* entries in the list that won't need to be seen for a while) and when this happens, the Loaded event DOES NOT FIRE.

Since I modify the content when the `TextBlock` was first Loaded, this breaks the binding association so when the `ListBoxItem` is recycled, it now contains old/incorrect data.

*Still no solution.*

I'm thinking about trying to use an IValueConvertor and somehow pass a reference to the binding target... now sure how yet though.

**Update 2: finally got it to work...**

Sticking with the `Loaded="..."` event handler, it is possible to disable recycling of previously-generated `ListBoxItem`s by [configuring the VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) used by the `ListBox` under the covers.

In the XAML for the `ListBox` set `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` to force a new ListBoxItem to be generated each time instead of recycling previously-generated ones.

This means the `Loaded` event handler is called every time and I can replace the ordinary text of the `TextBlock` with the `<Run>`s to produce dynamically coloured text.