# ListBoxItem not available at time of binding

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am needing to load 3 Listboxes(LB) in order. They load via `WCF RIA services`, after the 1st one is set I need to load the 2nd one using the first LB's text from the first element to query the 2nd list, and same for the third. It's like a tinkle down effect: 1st changes then update 2 and 3, if 2nd changes then update 3. The `ListBoxItem` is null in the completed events, but are available later. So how long do I have to wait for the item to be ready after the `CollectionViewSource` has been bound? I can even see the Selection_Changed event fire to -1(during load) and then back to 0(after load), but the ListBoxItem is not ready. Any other events I can use?

1st LB loads, use text of first element to load 2nd LB, use text of first element to load 3rd LB.  I have checked out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674451/how-to-get-the-listboxitem-for-an-item-in-listbox-on-bind-time), but have not found a `StatusChanged` event. The `ItemsChanged` event does not help.

Event map:

```
Load1stLsbAsync
(bind items in Completed event & Load2ndLsbAsync)
(bind items in Completed event & Load3rdLsbasync)
```

Comment: Use System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool check to attach datacontext

Comment: Thanks for that. I have looked at that property, but not sure how to use it. I was hoping for an event to listen for - none found so far.